Nav2 only sending rotating commands
As stated in the title, I'm currently working on a school project where we are using Nav2 to get a differential drive robot to autonomously navigate a given area. We are successfully mapping the environment using the SLAM toolbox and can generate a costmap, but when we use the 2D goal pose the robot just turns in place. We are echoing the cmd_vel output from Nav2 and it is consistent with this, just a constant output rotational velocity. Also, in the nav2 plugin for Rviz the display states that navigation is active but localization is inactive. Any help is much appreciated thanks! We have been modifying the mapping param file to decrease the cost map inflation layers and increase the robot speed.

Can you provide more information about the plugins that you are using? Which planner, controller and navigator? Which tree are you running? Could it be that it falls back to a behavior that spins in place because the localization is not enabled?
